# Collapsible IFrame Length Specification

Tags: php, html, iframe

Im trying to make somthing where I have an accordian with an IFrame inside and it expands when they click. When they click it expands but only a small bit. How can I make it so that it expands more. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style> 
#max200 {
    height: 85%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Minilesson Directory</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <form id="max200">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Creating A Project - Minilesson #1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K8YYw32TdEN9qd_tkypKQXDxwMh8uM3iAnUi5BcQ6jU/pub?embedded=true" height="85%" width="100%"></iframe></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result:
http://getthunkin.sanderjochems.nl/github/minilessons.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bootstrap Accordion, then you can set the height if the IFrame and it will change automaticly

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp#accordion